# Showing and hiding a div with jQuery

Tags: jquery

When you click on the link, it with display the div "somecontent". And if you click on the link again, it will hide. How can I make the div show when hovering over the link and hide when moving away instead of showing and hiding on click?

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".showcontent").click(function(){
    $(".somecontent").toggle("fast");
  });
});
</script>

<a class="showcontent" href="">Show</a>
<div class="somecontent">
   <p>some content</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace/remove the click event and add mouseover and mouseout (you can chain on the original element selection).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".showcontent").mouseover(function(){
    $(".somecontent").show();
  }).mouseout(function(){
    $(".somecontent").hide();
  });

  $(".somecontent").mouseout(function() { $(this).hide(); });

  $(".closelink").click(function() { $(this).parent().hide(); });
});
</script>

<a class="showcontent" href="">Show</a>
<div class="somecontent">
   <p>some content</p>
</div>
```

**Edit:**  With Colin's Suggestion..

A little refactoring of the elements, this should provide the results you want.

```
<div class="showcontent">
    <a href="#">Show</a>
    <div class="somecontent">
        <span class="closelink">Close</span>
        <p>some content<br />
            <a href="#">Link 1</a><br />
            <a href="#">Link 2</a><br />
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution works but when I try to move over the div, it hides. Is there a way for the div to stay open and hide when moving away like the link? I should of mentioned that at the beginning.

Comment: To a degree there is, but that's when the actually functionality starts to get quirky unless you provide a method for "closing" the open div.  Basically you can set it so that when you `mouseout` on the link it won't close the div but if you `mouseout` on the div it will close it.  This might not be the actual interaction you want though because if there is never a `mouseoever` on the div then it won't close if you just move away from the link.  Can you explain the exact behavior you want to occur (given the scenario described)?

Comment: Your a.showcontent needs to wrap around div.somecontent. But having a 'div' inside an 'a' is invalid and considering the 'a' does nothing but show another 'div', I suggest making it into a 'div'.
<div class="showcontent">
 <div class="somecontent">
  <p>content</p>
 </div>
</div>

Comment: Colin brings up a good point, if the anchor isn't required then some proper nesting can provide the solution you seem to want.

Comment: @Quintin: Okay, your suggestion would work. Could the div have a close link?

@Colin: I had the 'a' because it was going to be an actual link, but I just didn't put it there. When mousing over the div 'somecontent', it will contain a couple of more links. Would it still be invalid?

Comment: These things are possible.. Close Link, somecontent Links as well as the showcontent still acting like an anchor (with some styling and click handling)

Answer (score 2):

Simply replace "click" with a "mouseover"...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".showcontent").mouseover(function(){
    $(".somecontent").toggle("fast");
  });
});
</script>


<a class="showcontent" href="">Show</a>
<div class="somecontent">
   <p>some content</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

RE Solving the "hover over the div" problem.  You could set up something like this:

```
var revealLink = $('.showcontent');
var revealDiv = $('.somecontent');
var revealTimeout = 0;

// we attach the mouseover/out events to both.
revealLink.add(revealDiv).hover(function() {
  clearTimeout(revealTimeout);
  revealDiv.show();
}, function() {
  // give user 500 ms to get over the other element to not hide.
  revealTimeout = setTimeout(function() { revealDiv.hide(); }, 500);
});
```

Where your mouse out handler sets a timeout that gets cleared as you mouseover the element again.